# MYSQL search multiple records in the same table with the same first part of primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:
`SALE(SALE_CODE,SALE_DATE)` and
`SALE_ITEM(SALE_CODE,ITEM_CODE,QUANTITY,PRICE)`
with `SALE_CODE` and `SALE_CODE,ITEM_CODE` as primary keys respectively.

I want to find out the sale with the biggest income.

I can only figure out how to do it if each sale contains only one item

```
SELECT SALE_CODE,PRICE*QUANTITY 
FROM SALE_ITEM
WHERE PRICE*QUANTITY =(SELECT MAX(PRICE*QUANTITY)                                       
FROM SALE_ITEM);
```

But if there are multiple records on the SALE_ITEM table with the same SALE_CODE but with different ITEM_CODE, I don't know what to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select sale_code, sum(price * quantity)
    from sale_item
    group by sale_code
    order by sum(price * quantity) desc
    limit 1;
```

[SQLFiddle example here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d84dc/2)

Comment: limit 1 is because i only want the first one?